# How to set screen-specific scale?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, scaling

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and a 768p screen that I hook up to a 4k (3840/2160) screen when at home. I'm using *Join displays* as the display mode. Here is what it looks like in Settings:

[image: Display settings]

Changing the scale on one tab also changes it on the other, so if i keep the scale at 100%, everything is fine on the laptop screen, and extremely small on the external screen. If i bump it up to 200%, everything is bloated and enormous on the laptop and nice on the external screen.

For the moment, I just set the resolution of the external screen to 1080p, but I've got a 4k screen, so it's really a bummer.

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+312 (normal left inverted right x 
axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis 
y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   3840x2160     30.00 +  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x2160     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

So is there a way to set a scale *per screen*? In my case 100% for one and 200% for the other?

Comment: I think that with your setup, with two vastly different resolutions, "Single screen" would be ideal. Unless you really need two screens simultaneously. (or "Single display", don't know what the setting is called in English)

Comment: @SteveAdmin as per Jos comment.. if you can stick with "Single Display" as your preferred choice when you connect your laptop. You can have the all available resolutions with 4K Screen.

Comment: @PRATAP & Jos (the @ wont work twice) : Yes, i know, but the point of the post was to find a way to use both screens at once.

Comment: @SteveAdmin You are rite.. So you want to use "Join Displays" mode with 2 different resolutions.

Comment: @SteveAdmin can you paste the output of `xrandr` when you connected the displays and in "Join Displays" mode.

Comment: @SteveAdmin try `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 3840x2160`

Comment: @SteveAdmin if above did not work try `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 3840x2160+1366+0`

Comment: Well, my screen went back to 4k, and everything went back to extremely small.

Comment: @SteveAdmin from the out put you posted. Choose any one resolution for HDMI-1-1 and change the above command accordingly.

Comment: @SteveAdmin Hi, Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PRATAP I used a command suggested on reddit :




> xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --auto --output eDP-1-1 --auto --panning 3840x2160+3840+0 --scale 2x2 --right-of HDMI-1-1





and it broke my whole desktop, and after searching two hours how to reverse it I figured i would just reinstall Ubuntu. Which i did. I wont be having the monitor for a month, so I 'm not gonna look for a fix right now.